# How to review polygon point by point

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QPolygonF` and I want to get all its `QPointF`s one by one. I have no idea how to make it.

P.S. What actually does `operator>>` in `QPolygonF` do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in documentation QPolygonF is actually inherited from QVector, so you can access vertexes in a same way you would work with QVector

Comment: Thanks, I truly forgot about it. By the way, can u tell me what can I do with `operator>>` cause I don't understand description in documentation?

Comment: It's just (de-)serialization to Qt streams.. Very useful if you need to store/retrieve things.